# Generate a json list by parsing a list

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have javascript `const` currently defined as :

```
const IMAGES =
        [{
                src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        {
                src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        
        {
                src: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        {
            src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
            thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
            thumbnailWidth: 156,
            thumbnailHeight: 156
        }]
```

It's currently hardcoded and not dynamically updateable, So I have created a list which is extracted from a json with just URL inside and look like this :

```
["https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/16/23/10/spice-370114_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/13/18/47/spices-887348_1280.jpg", 
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/20/13/30/kitchen-731351_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/40/writing-828911_1280.jpg"]
```

the JSON is looking like this:

```
"classpic": ["https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/16/23/10/spice-370114_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/13/18/47/spices-887348_1280.jpg", 
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/20/13/30/kitchen-731351_1280.jpg",
            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/40/writing-828911_1280.jpg"]
```

So i am just getting the field by doing `Class.classpic` but I was expected to be able to run a kind of `map` function which can rebuild the const which where hardcoded before. Something like:

```
Class.classpic.map((pic, i) => {
    return ("
        src: {pic},
        thumbnail: {pic},
        thumbnailWidth: 156,
        thumbnailHeight: 156
 ");
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the quotes

You can also modify the thumbnail source if needed

```js
const classpic = ["https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/16/23/10/spice-370114_1280.jpg",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/13/18/47/spices-887348_1280.jpg",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/20/13/30/kitchen-731351_1280.jpg",
  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/02/10/40/writing-828911_1280.jpg"
]
const list = classpic.map((pic, i) => ({
  src: pic,
  thumbnail: pic.replace("1280","_480"), // for example
  thumbnailWidth: 156,
  thumbnailHeight: 156
}));

console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear, but maybe you mean like this:

```
const IMAGES = Class.classpic.map(pic => ({
  src: pic,
  thumbnail: pic,
  thumbnailWidth: 156,
  thumbnailHeight: 156
}));
```